# How to Update Coupon Code Objects in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, coupon

How to Update Coupon Code Objects in Woocommerce (Wordpress).

```
$beforeadduseremail="test@gmail.com";

update_post_meta( 21, 'email_restrictions', $beforeadduseremail);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in different ways:

Using Wordpress `get_post_meta()` and `update_post_meta()` on `customer_email` meta key:

```
$coupon_post_id = 21; // The post ID
$user_email     = 'test@gmail.com'; // The email to be added

// Get existing email restrictions
$email_restrictions = (array) get_post_meta( $coupon_post_id, 'customer_email', true );

// Add the new email to existing emails
if ( ! in_array( $user_email, $email_restrictions ) ) {
    $email_restrictions[] = $user_email;
}

// Set a back updated email restrictions array
update_post_meta( $coupon_post_id, 'customer_email', $email_restrictions );
```

Using [CRUD methods](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) on the `WC_Coupon` object instance (since WooCommerce 3):

```
$coupon_code = 'happysummer'; // The coupon code
$user_email  = 'test@gmail.com'; // The email to be added

    // Get an instance of the WC_Coupon object
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );

    // Get email restrictions
    $email_restrictions = (array) $coupon->get_email_restrictions();

    // Add the customer email to the restrictions array
    $email_restrictions[] = $customer_email;

    // set the new array of email restrictions
    $coupon->set_email_restrictions( $email_restrictions );

    // Save the coupon data
    $coupon->save();
```